# Python Selenium Change Chrome Options Half Way

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to download multiple files (more than 1000) using Selenium automating Chrome but the chrome_options only able to be set during the initiation. My downloads are categories by folders and I would like to download all the files into the created folders during runtime.

any help or suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to use Selenium for file downloading?

Comment: Because I need to manipulate a few clicking steps before entering the downloads

Comment: Yes, but the downloading link is always the same. Why not just to use it directly?

Comment: My download link is not the same, so I couldnt use it.

Comment: I mean file download URL is always the same - it doesn't depend on the steps you're making in browser

Comment: No, the download URL is NOT the same. It is more or less a dynamic table that contain multiple links, where all links are updated from another site. Thats why my URL is different everytime.